# Xcode 7 - Swift - Use of undeclared type 'UITableviewcell'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, types

**THE ERROR WAS A TYPO, PLEASE DELETE**

I'm just new to swift and this is probably only a very basic problem.
If anyone could help that would be fantastic.

I was following a youtube tutorial on how to make a slide out menu in swift/xcode and this bug came up. I have double checked and I have written the exact same code as on the tutorial. I have researched and tried to fix it but can't.

I know the bug is the:

```
as UITableViewCell
```

at the end of the 5th last line of code. But I don't know why and the tutorial says to include it. Please Help.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class backTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var TableArray = [String]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    TableArray = ["Hello", "Second", "World"]
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableArray.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableviewCell

    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `UITableviewCell` != `UITableViewCell`

Comment: so what the error is?

Comment: have you registered your cell?

Comment: either typo but i dont think so because then it would give compile error. i guess cellIdentifier is not set correctly at storyboard. Please check uitableviewcell's identifier in your storyboard

Comment: @MihribanMinaz There is a compile error, it's in the title of the question: "Use of undeclared type 'UITableviewcell'". And you can see in OP's code that it is indeed the typo.

Comment: Ooo sorry i didnt see that :) @EricD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippet you have a typo.

This line

`var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableviewCell`

should be

`var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell`

With a capital V when you do the cast to `UITableViewCell` (`as UITableViewCell`)

Hopefully that is what is causing your problems

Comment: Please avoid posting answers to "typo" questions. These questions are only helpful for OP, not for any other user, and they will be closed and deleted eventually. It's better to just comment and flag / vote to close. Thanks. :)

Comment: I see your point @EricD, Live and learn eh :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, that fixed it :)